# From number to formatted datetime in R

Tags: r

I have a field into a dataframe of class numeric.
I want to convert that into a date time format.

value: 1353959527000000
expected: 2012-11-26 11:52:07.000-08:00

**How do I do that in R?**

I tried:
Using lubridate or default Posix conversion and nothing produced the date above. Read a bunch of posts and still not figuring out what I am doing wrong.

```
dn <- 1353959527000000 
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(dn)),origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
```

output was something super off the expected date with some gibberish.
Same output trying this

```
as_datetime(1353959527000000, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00")
```

Comment: You have microseconds there. This works: `as.POSIXct(1353959527000000/1e6, origin='1970-01-01')`

Comment: For reference, "normal epoch seconds" would only be `as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2012-11-26 11:52:07"))`, giving 10 characters in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's FAQ and a repeat question, but as @r2evans told you, the right *scale* helps.  As does eg `anytime::anytime` as it frees you from using the origin etc pp:

```
R> dn <- 1353959527000000 
R> anytime::anytime(dn/1e6)      # local time
[1] "2012-11-26 13:52:07 CST"
R> anytime::utctime(dn/1e6)      # utctime
[1] "2012-11-26 19:52:07 UTC"
R>
```